# Linux application that bundles multiple incoming audio and video streams into one container file?

Tags: video, streaming, ffmpeg, gstreamer, vlc

I've been assigned to implement a video on-demand service for a local university. Different aspects of the lectures (video, audio, screen cast, white board) will be recorded. During a lecture all these data streams arrive at one Linux server. This server should transcode and bundle all these streams into one container (Matroska) file.

My options seem to be:

- Write a GStreamer application
- do something with FFMPEG
- do something with VLC
- ...?

Has anyone done something similar in the past? Can you recommend something?

**Edit**
For those interested, here are a few of my findings:

- Matroska is not a good format for streaming (it's possible, but it's not its primary intent)
- For Flash streaming you can use MPEG4
- If you want to combine different videos into one video where each subvideo occupies a rectangular portion of the total screen, then this [GStreamer script](http://git.gnome.org/cgit/usability-lab/tree/eb1304-to-ogg.sh#n93) is useful (I found it on this [blog post](http://blogs.gnome.org/halfline/2009/10/11/video-4-way-split-screen-gstreamer-pipeline/)).
- Desktop capture works fine with VLC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC has a straight forward GUI for configure stream capturing (docs on doing it [via the command line](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html)). I've used the stream capture before and it is super easy, even transcoding on the fly.

I think the bigger question is how do you envision having multiple visual streams (video, screen cast, and white board) simultaneously?  Are you going to manually mix these into a video in which you show the screen cast then cut to the lecturer? If so, you might want to look into a video editor like [avidemux](http://avidemux.org/) or [Kino](http://www.kinodv.org/) ([a list of more options](http://www.programmerfish.com/10-free-apps-that-turn-your-ubuntu-into-video-studio/)).

Personally, I would set it up so that VLC captures your primary video and audio into a single MKV file.  I would simetaneously capture any other video elements into separate files.  Once the lecture is over, I would use avidemux to manually splice the primary video to include those other video elements, such as screen shots.

Comment: Writing Simultaneousness video/audio capture into disk drive is a sector flooding. Why not we can write using Gstreamer the same thing in ports, as a buffer? Much more reliable from hardware perspective. Your listed suggestion does not show such implementing, can you show us more about this. Because i come to this url all the time while i am searching.